# SQL structure with JOIN

Tags: php, sql, database, join, structure

I'm having some trouble figuring out how I should build my database for this project i'm currently working on. Fishing-related.

I'm just not sure how to set up my tables.

Table 1(ID, username, email etc)
Table 2(fish, weight, length etc)

How do i join these two tables? Should I have a column named ID in the 2nd table aswell? Because I need to know which user uploaded what fish. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes you need to add a column for User ID in `Table 2` otherwise you won't be able to tell which user uploaded what fish.

Comment: do the tables have any field(s) in common? if not, then you can't directly join them. In order to use a **RELATIONAL** database, you need to have data that's somehow **RELATED**.

Comment: No, no relations right now. I'll have to look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you're table structure I think it's best to change the **id** name in table 1 to *user_id* and add a column in the second table also named *user_id*. Joining using the columns is then very simple using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 USING (user_id)
```

Other possibility would be to add a column named *user_id* (or something else) to table2 and create a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = table1.id
```

In this case, you set the columns to use for the join in the 'ON .. = ..' structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to, and that is called Relation Databases this is example

```
Users (UserID, UserName, Password)
Fish (FishID, UserID, FishName, Length, Weight)
```

and then you connect them using UserID

```
select u.UserName, f.FishName, f.Length, f.Weight
 from Users u
 LEFT JOIN Fish f on (f.UserID=u.UserID)
```

and if you are looking for specific user then just add at the end

```
WHERE u.UserID=@UserID
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. And this is all one big query?

Comment: in my experience this is basic query, and very small.